# ошибка при использовании query

Tags: javascript, jquery

вот на такой пустячок

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>

<form>
    Enter word: <input type="text" name="word" id="ajax_word">
</form>


<script>
    $('#ajax_word').input(function(ev) 
    {
        console.log(this.val());
    });
</script>
```

ругается так: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).input is not a function

очевидно где-то чего-то не так написал. в гугле к этому вопросу по разному подходят, в основном пишут о том что пути к библиотеке должны быть правильные, но зачем ее качать если можно ссылку вставить?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно использовать не `.input`, а `.on("input",`.
А вместо `this` у jquery используется конструкция `$(this)`.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>

<form>
    Enter word: <input type="text" name="word" id="ajax_word">
</form>
<div></div>

<script>
  $(function(){
    $('#ajax_word').on('input',function(ev) 
    {
        $('div').text($(this).val());
    });
  });
</script>
```

https://codepen.io/baryonyx/pen/aYpNxw